# How to make a 3D (X,Y,Z)shape in a 2D space (x,y)

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, trigonometry

I would like to know the equations needed to do this and why it is. 
I want to create a 3D shape that can grow, rotate and pan in a 2d shape.

Comment: If you want to know the math behind projecting a 3d object in a 2d space, look for [3d projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). If you want to implement something in 3d and appreciate it in a browser (2d), look for [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API) or a WebGL library like [Three.js](https://threejs.org/). BTW, the question is probably too broad for an actually answer (or off-topic, depending of what you want to know).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot of help